# Random syntax errors in script

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, syntax

I have a very puzzling problem in Python 2.7
I use Notepadd++
After developing a script of no more than 25 lines, when running it on Python
it gives me "Syntax Errors" on different lines of the script on re-running it
even if the that line runs OK on the interpreter. 
For instance, on simple statements like assigning a value to a variable, the second or third assignment to that variable gives me the syntax error.
I went to the length of typing line by line on the interpreter and each executed
with success, arriving at the proper result in the last line.
I tried to re-write and run the same script (copying line by line) on IDLE (which gives me also random line syntax errors) and lastly resorting to Microsoft Notepad. No better.
Please your help will make me understand such a complex language as Python. Thank you.
I use WIndows 10 and the script is a test of Hashing and AES encrypting from Crypto.Hash / Crypto.cipher.

## I am ready to furnish a copy of the script.

Thank you both for trying to help. Below I am posting my script and at the end of it, commented, is the exact response from the interpreter. The caret is correctly pointing to the end of the variable . The print command after the call to padmessage() is improperly formatted, it is in a single line. Thank you again!
....................................................

```
  # bobo.py  
  def padmessage():  
      global message, pad  
      if len(message) % 16 == 0:  
          return  
      padding = 16 - len(message) % 16  
      message = message + pad * padding  
  def unpadmessage():  
      global message, pad
      message = message.rstrip(pad)  
  pad = '&'  
  key = 'keykey'  
  print('\nOriginal key : %s' % key)  
  from Crypto.Hash import SHA256  
  print('\n Key : %s \nLength of key: %i' % (key, len(key))  
  key = SHA256.new(key).hexdigest()  
  print('\nHashed key %s : \nLength : %i' % (skey, len(key))  
  key = key[0:32]  
  print('\nResized key : %s \nLength : %i' %(key, len(key))  
  message = 'sjqwkweoewoykjjasdo' * 31  
  print('\nMessage : %s \nLength of message: %i ' % (message, len(message))  
  padmessage()  
  print('\nPadded message : %s \nLength of message: %s' % (message,  len(message))  
  from Crypto.Cipher import AES  
  IV = key[16:32]  
  print('\nIV : %s \nIV length : %s ' % (IV, len(IV))  
  crypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)  
  message = crypt.encrypt(message)  
  print('\nEncrypted message : %s ' % cypher)  
  decrypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)  
  message = decrypt.decrypt(cypher)  
  print('\nAfter decryption : %s' % message)  
  unpadmessage()  
  print('\nAfter unpadding : %s' % message)  

  # My call in python27:  
  # execfile('bobo.py')  

  # The response from Python:  

  # Traceback (most recent call last):  
      # File "stdin", line 1 in <module>  
      # File "bobo.py", line 16  
        # key = SHA256.new(key).hexdigest()  
          # ^  
   # SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
   # >>>
```

Auuuuugh! Very humbled and apologetic. My error was in the print statement, it was missing a parenthesis at the end. And since I was updating the print statement with a single copy of it the error would appear at random (and increasing lines) on my script. The clue was given by John la Rooy who posted that and error could "appear at a distance". Thank you! It appeared in the next line (key =) throwing me off completely.
Again, very grateful... "learning is making mistakes"... (not too many please!)

Comment: Put at least one of the lines giving you the error and the exact text of the error. This sounds far-fetched but there's currently no way to evaluate your claim.

Answer (score -1):

A syntax error can be caused at a distance from the line it is reported on, for example if you are missing a parenthesis or other bracket on an earlier line.

The problem below is not on the line with the print statement.

```
>>> def hypot(x, y):
...     return ((x ** 2) + (y ** 2) ** 0.5
... 
... print hypot(3, 4)
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print hypot(3, 4)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The REPL gives us a clue here, by not switching the prompt back to `>>>`. But you won't see that in your editor.

If you can include the entire 25 lines in your question, it will be easy for us to spot.